# subversion doesn't see my updates via python script

Tags: python, django, svn, unix, pycharm

I have written a Django command along these lines:

```
def handle(self, *args, **options):
    from django.conf import settings
    import subprocess
    full_path = settings.PROJECT_ROOT+"/somedir/"
    subprocess.Popen('make -C '+full_path ,shell=True).wait()
```

The Makefile executes this pseudo code:

```
recompile & cp -r

External/
    somedir/somefiles

to

Projectroot/
    somedir/somefiles
```

This works exactly like expected, however something odd happends:

Every time I run the command, the files are overwritten and the timestamp is updated. However subversion does not recognize my changes, but the django command `collectstatic` does infact..

Perhaps I need to force a svn update somehow?

Comment: the files that are changing, are they ignored by svn for some reason?  run `svn status --no-ignore` to check.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be anything wrong.. But if I delete the files from the projectroot path initially and run Make via the command once, the files are not versioned, then I add them to svn. Then I run the command again. In my Finder the timestamps are changed so the files are overwritten, however svn doesn't see a change, whilest collectstatic does

Comment: Copying a file manually from the external dir to the project dir is infact recognized, but via the command line it's not :S

Comment: Perhaps a permissions thing? Are perms/owner/group maintained after running the script?

Comment: @Jon that sounds like a plausible cause. Instead of using Makefile (externally) I used django itself to move the files, which did cause svn to recognize changes.. thanks.. I'm not sure how to work around this yet :-)

Comment: Just run everything as root :P  (don't do this!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too localized. Vote to close and keep it as a reference for those who are interested.